For a $q$-form $\varphi$, $\nabla\varphi=0$ if and only if $\nabla(*\varphi)=0$, where $*$ is the Hodge star operator.
I know the formula that connects differentiation and covariant differentiation is
$$d \varphi\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{q+1}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{q+1}(-1)^{i-1}\left(\nabla_{X_{i}} \varphi\right)\left(X_{1}, \cdots, \hat{X}_{i}, \cdots, X_{q+1}\right).$$
So
$$(-1)^q(*\delta\varphi)\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{n-q+1}\right)=d (*\varphi)\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{n-q+1}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{q+1}(-1)^{i-1}(\nabla_{X_{i}} 
(*\varphi))\left(X_{1}, \cdots, \hat{X}_{i}, \cdots, X_{n-q+1}\right).$$
But this method won't let me get the equivalence since right hand side is the sum of multiple items and I don't know what else to do. Any help would be appreciated!

One can avoid tedious calculations and consider the following: for any $p\in M$, let $\{e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$ be a local orthonormal frame around $p$ such that $\nabla e_i (p) = 0$ for each $i=1, \cdots, n$. This can be found by parallel translating an orthornormal basis at $p$ along radial geodesics. Let $\{\omega_1, \cdots, \omega_n\}$ be its dual frame. Then one also has $\nabla \omega_i (p)= 0$ for $i=1, \cdots, n$. Locally one can write
$$ \phi =\sum_{i_1< \cdots < i_q} \phi_{i_1\cdots i_q} \omega_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega_{i_q}.$$
This implies
$$ \nabla \phi= \sum _{i_1< \cdots < i_q} \nabla \phi_{i_1\cdots i_q} \otimes  \omega_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega_{i_q}$$
at $p$. Hence $\nabla \phi (p)=0$ if and only if $\nabla \phi_{i_1\cdots i_q} (p) = 0$ for all $i_1<\cdots < i_q$.
Similarly,
$$ * \phi = \sum_{i_1< \cdots < i_q} \phi_{i_1\cdots i_q} *(\omega_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega_{i_q})$$
and since
$$*(\omega_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega_{i_q}) = \pm \omega_{j_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega_{j_{n-q}}$$
for some $j_1<\cdots <j_{n-q}$, one concludes that
$$ \nabla(* \phi) = \sum_{i_1< \cdots < i_q} \nabla\phi_{i_1\cdots i_q} \otimes *(\omega_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega_{i_q})$$
at $p$. Hence $\nabla (*\phi) = 0$ at $p$ if and only if $\nabla \phi_{i_1\cdots i_q} (p)=  0$ for each $i_1<\cdots < i_q$. Hence $\nabla \phi (p) = 0$ if and only if $\nabla (*\phi )(p)  =0$. Since $p\in M$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $\nabla \phi  =0$ if and only if $\nabla (* \phi)  =0$.

I just wanted to comment that this is the analogue of classical computations in normal coordinates to make the Christoffel symbols vanish at an arbitrary point.

Extra remarks for OP: in fact this computation shows that $\nabla(\star\phi)=\star(\nabla\phi)$, where the latter Hodge star is defined by acting on the $q$-form nature of $\nabla\phi$ seen as a section of $\text{Hom}\left(TM,\bigwedge^q(T^*M)\right)\cong T^*M\otimes\bigwedge^q(T^*M)$. Hence, the claim follows. Even more abstractly, since $\star$ is essentially “a function of the metric”, it follows by metric compatibility of the Levi-Civita connection that $\nabla(\star\phi)=\star\nabla\phi$; but of course this is concretely seen in the “normal-coordinate”-like computation done here.
